# Loop for and return to beginning

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I would like to get this result:

```
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
...
19 1

0 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
...
19 2

...

0 10
1 10
2 10
3 10
...
19 10
```

but i don't know what i'm doing wrong, using this code:

```
$p=0;
for($i=0; $i<40; $i++)
{
    if($i%20 == 0)
    {
        $p+=1;
        $i=0;
    } else {
        echo $i.' '.$p;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

When i try to run the code, it takes forever. What am i doing wrong? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Which part of this code did you expect to stop the loop?

Comment: You reset $i when it reaches 20, so it will never reach 40, and so the loop will never end. Sorry to say, but if you have problems with this, you will have many more and more challenging problems to get an average problem solved with programming.

Comment: The reason your code goes into infinite loop is because of the `if` conditional. when `i` reaches `20`, it's reset to `0`! This would repeat what has just happened until `i` reached `20`. It's just a logical fallacy and you can figure it out pretty easily.

Comment: After $i=0 i wanted to add the line that would make the loop begins again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use nested for loops

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++)
        echo $j . ' ' . $i . '<br>';

    echo '<br>';
}
```